# Laravel Edit Function redirect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm coding a quiz app and I'm trying to add an edit function to it. With a click on the 'Submit' Button I get the error **Missing required parameters for [Route: quiz/show] [URI: quiz/{quiz}].**
How can I fix that? I'm a beginner in Laravel so it would be nice if you could help me.

My web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuizController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::get('quiz/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@create');
Route::post('quiz', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@store');
Route::get('quiz/{quiz?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@show')->name('quiz/show');

Route::get('quiz/{quiz}/questions/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@create');
Route::post('quiz/{quiz}/questions', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@store');
Route::delete('quiz/{quiz}/questions/{question}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@destroy');
Route::get('question/edit', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@edit')->name('question/edit');
Route::patch('question/{question}', '\App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@update')->name('question/update');

Route::get('startquiz/{quiz}-{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\StartQuizController@show');
Route::post('startquiz/{quiz}-{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\StartQuizController@store');
```

My QuestionController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\Quiz;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Quiz $quiz) {
        return view('question.create', compact('quiz'));
    }

    public function store(Quiz $quiz) {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'question.question' => 'required',
            'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
        ]);

        $question = $quiz->questions()->create($data['question']);
        $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);

        return redirect('/quiz/'.$quiz->id);
    }

    public function destroy(Quiz $quiz, Question $question) {
        $question->answers()->delete();
        $question->delete();

        return redirect($quiz->path());
    }
    public function edit(Question $question) {
       return view('quiz.edit', compact('question'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Question $question, Quiz $quiz) {
        //$request->validate([
            //'question' => 'required',
        //]);
        $question->update($request->all());
        //dd($quiz);
        return redirect()->route('quiz/show', ['quiz' => $question->quiz])
                        -> with('success', 'Question updated successfully');
    }
}
```

My edit.blade

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <body>


        <h1>Edit Question</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('question/update',$question->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="question">Question</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" value="{{ $question->name }}"placeholder="Enter Question">
                                <small id="questionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type in your edited question.</small>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check if `$quiz` is not empty in `update` function

Comment: @HarpalSingh How can I check that?

Comment: print `dd($quiz);` before `return redirect...` and check if it has not null value.
If `$quiz` is null, you can try `Route::get('quiz/{quiz?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\QuizController@show')->name('quiz/show');` quiz as optional parameter.

Comment: @HarpalSingh Yeah it's null, but with your code it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route for "update" does not take any parameters. Your `update` method of the Controller looks like it wants to use Route Model Binding but there are no parameters so you are getting a non existing instance of `Quiz` which doesn't have an `id` so its trying to use `null` which you can not do for route parameters when generating URLs.

You need to adjust your route URI definition to take a parameter for `question` and `quiz`. Maybe:

```
Route::patch('quiz/{quiz}/question/{question}', ...)
```

If you don't want to use route parameters for quiz or question you will have to make adjustments to the controller to get the information from the request inputs.

Other quick option:

You should be able to derive the quiz from the question so you don't **need** to pass the quiz along:

```
Route::patch('question/{question}', ...)

public function update(Request $request, Question $question)
{
    $question->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('quiz/show', ['quiz' => $question->quiz])
        ->with('success', 'Question updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I have the same problem as before

Comment: the way your controller method is setup, you would need route parameters to match `quiz` and `question` to use the code you have ... if you want to go about it a different way that can be done as well

Comment: I edited the patch-Route as you did. But I get the error ```Missing required parameters for [Route: question/update] [URI: quiz/{quiz}/question/{question}]. (View: /home/vagrant/code/quizapp/resources/views/quiz/edit.blade.php)``` I edited my code in the question

Comment: right because another parameter was added that isn't being passed when calling the `route` helper to generate the URL now ...  try the simpler update instead, less things to change

Comment: It still doesn't work. 
```Missing required parameters for [Route: question/update] [URI: question/{question}]. (View: /home/vagrant/code/quizapp/resources/views/quiz/edit.blade.php)```

Comment: you are also missing the route parameter for your `edit` route ... its the same issues

Comment: xD How can I fix that?

Comment: you have to have parameters in the route URI if you want Route Model Binding to happen ... your `edit` method has typehinted `Question $question` but there is no route paremeter for `question` in the route definition